# Many to Many Relationship in Laravel Errror: The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Please,  I don't know what I am doing wrong. I am creating an application. In the app, I want user to be able to select favourite category and save it to the database. I have **users** table, **categories** table, and I created a pivot table **category_user**.

I returned the `category` in my `user` model

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(category::class);
}
```

I returned the users in my `category` model

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(user::class);
}
```

I created `onboard.blade.php` in my view-

```
    <form action="#" method="POST">
      @csrf
      @foreach($categories as $category)
        <div class="radio-item">
        <input type="radio" id="ritema" required>
          <label for="ritemb">{{ $category -> title }}</label>
        </div>
        @endforeach

        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-12 text-center">
            <button type="submit">Proceed to Authors</button>
          </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

I also create a new function in my `CategoriesController`

```
public function categoryUser ()
{
    $user = \App\User::all();
    $user = categories()->attach

    return redirect ( route ('onboarding_author'));

}
```

In `web.php`, I added

```
Route::post('/onboard', 'CategoriesController@categoryUser');
```

When I tried to submit the form, it returned

**The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.**

Comment: Replace `action="#"` with `action="{{ url('/onboard') }}"` for starters, `$user = categories()->attach` is a syntax error (missing `;` and attach is a method `()`, missing params), this wouldn't be a `many-to-many` if you only want the user to have 1 favourite category, etc etc.

Comment: _this wouldn't be a many-to-many if you only want the user to have 1 favourite category, etc etc._

Please what would you advice I do here to  make it many-to-many. Thanks.

Comment: If you wanted to use a `many-to-many`, then you'd have to have a boolean `favourite` column, so that one of your attached `category` models is a `favourite`. Otherwise, you'd need a `favourite_category_id` column on `users`, etc.

Comment: I have added this `{{ url('/onboard') }}` and it redirect to the correct view but doesn't submit to the database

Comment: Like I said in the first comment, `$user = categories()->attach` is not valid.

Comment: I have done research, I added the code below to my controller
<br/>
`public function categoryUser (Request $request)`
  `  {`
        `$category = Category::find($request->input('category_id'));`
        `$user = User::where('user_id', Auth::id());`
        `$category->users()->attach($user->id);`'
<br/>
But it's returned error
**Call to a member function users() on null**

Comment: Try this `Category::query()->create($request->all())->users()->attach($user->id);`

Comment: I have, it's not working @smartrahat